# An error occurs when Spring Resource Server tries to parse a valid JWT. Invalid JSON: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server, spring-resource-server

I am trying to achieve content on resource server with WebFlux.
I am sure, that my oauth2 authorization server works correctly and returns valid token.

Request, that my resource server achieves:

```
2023-11-30T04:51:01.070+01:00 DEBUG 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received 
[GET / HTTP/1.1
accept-encoding: gzip
user-agent: ReactorNetty/1.1.12
host: localhost:8090
accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer ya29.valid-token-that-i-removed

]
```

After that spring starts to validate request:

```
2023-11-30T04:51:01.102+01:00 DEBUG 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2023-11-30T04:51:01.103+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.103+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.104+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.105+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.106+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.107+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@158b5fff]]]
2023-11-30T04:51:01.108+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.108+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-11-30T04:51:01.108+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.108+01:00 DEBUG 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2023-11-30T04:51:01.109+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with JwtAuthenticationProvider (1/2)
2023-11-30T04:51:01.110+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder        : Failed to parse token

java.text.ParseException: Invalid unsecured/JWS/JWE header: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser.parse(JWTParser.java:71) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.parse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:144) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:133) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at net.maslyna.oauth2.resource.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2023-11-30T04:51:01.112+01:00 DEBUG 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
2023-11-30T04:51:01.113+01:00 TRACE 13480 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Invalid unsecured/JWS/JWE header: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at net.maslyna.oauth2.resource.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.BadJwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Invalid unsecured/JWS/JWE header: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.parse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:148) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:133) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Invalid unsecured/JWS/JWE header: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser.parse(JWTParser.java:71) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.parse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:144) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Controller on client service:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth/users")
public class UserController {
    private final WelcomeClient welcomeClient;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return welcomeClient.getWelcome();
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig on client service:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/google"))
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

WebFluxClient on client service:

```java
@HttpExchange(url = "http://localhost:8090")
public interface WelcomeClient {
    @GetExchange("/")
    String getWelcome();
}
```

WebClientConfig on client service:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WelcomeClient welcomeClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        return httpServiceProxyFactory(authorizedClientManager).createClient(WelcomeClient.class);
    }

    private HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);

//        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("google");
        oauth2Client.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();
        WebClientAdapter client = WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient);
        return HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(client).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .authorizationCode()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

Resource server config:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String jwtIssuerUri;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(jwtIssuerUri);
    }
}
```

I think, that I must send only token value in JSON, without headers etc. or something else.
I don't have much expirience on spring reactive, and webflux with oauth2 I am trying for 1st time. I am trying to do simple oauth2 client allready for few weeks, and don't have any progress.

Comment: You say that you're using WebFlux, but your config classes and logs indicate you are not because `SecurityFilterChain` and `JwtDecoder` are for servlet-based applications. Please see [OAuth2 WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/index.html) docs, specifically the [JWT configuration example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot). Without more details, I'm unable to determine the cause but it seems you have one or more configuration problems.

Comment: See [WebFlux Resource Server Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/reactive/webflux/java/oauth2/resource-server) and the readme for a concrete working example, or the demo-client sample in the [Spring Authorization Server Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples) (which is not a WebFlux application).

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I used Webflux only for HTTP request, It could not to produce exceptions in this way. But, I rewrote SecurityConfig in Resource server like it was in [WebFlux Resource Server Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/reactive/webflux/java/oauth2/resource-server) and I had same error.

Comment: After that I saw, that I had made a mistake in `WebClientConfig`, and my `WelcomeClient` sends `accsess_token` value in auth header, not `id_token` value. I will search how to resolve it and after that I will write an answer. But knowing the problem is already an advantage.